# Creating custom Link Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am very new to C#. Please help me out.

```
 class BasicPay
    {
        public int employee_personal_id { get; set; }
        public int grade_id { get; set; }
        public int position_id { get; set; }
        public Int32 base_pay { get; set; }
        public Int32 housing { get; set; }

    private static void getEmployeeForEmpFinance(int empPersionalinfoID)
        {

            var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();
            var query = from c in context.Employee_Financial
                        join d in context.Employee_Employ on
                        c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id equals d.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id
                        where c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == empPersionalinfoID
                        select new { c.ID, c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id, c.Base_Pay, c.Housing_Allowance, d.Grade_Id };
            var y = query.SingleOrDefault();
            var basic = new List<BasicPay>();

           **basic.Add(y.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id,y.Grade_Id);** // THIS IS WHAT I DO NOT UNDERSTAND

        }

}
```

The commented line is what i am not getting. I created by own class of BasicPay. Now how do I add my results into this? Please help me out. i am in dire need!

EDITED-----
So i used the suggestion from one of the guy below and it work and i've tried to better it.. below is my new code.

```
private static BasicPay  getEmployeeForEmpFinance(int empPersionalinfoID)
{

    var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();
    var query = from c in context.Employee_Financial
                join d in context.Employee_Employ on
                c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id equals d.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id
                where c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == empPersionalinfoID
                select new BasicPay
                {
                    employee_personal_id = c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id,
                    grade_id = d.Grade_Id,
                    base_pay = c.Base_Pay,
                    housing = c.Housing_Allowance
                };
  var y = query.SingleOrDefault();

  return y;
}
```

public static void employeeEmploy(int payperiodID){

```
            var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();
            var query = from c in context.Payroll_Batch
                        where c.PayperiodID == payperiodID
                        select c.Payroll_GroupID;
            int y = query.SingleOrDefault();

            Debug.WriteLine("group id: " + y);

            var query2 = from i in context.Employee_Employ
                         where (i.Payroll_Group == y && i.Grade_Id != null)
                         select new { i.ID,i.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id, i.Date_of_Appointment, i.Date_of_Employment, i.Grade_Id, i.Substantive_designation };
           var  empEmploy = query2.ToList();

           var basics = new List<BasicPay>();

           foreach (var x in empEmploy)
           {
               basics.Add(getEmployeeForEmpFinance(x.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id));


           }
           for (int c=0; c < basics.Count(); c++)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(basics.ElementAt(c).employee_personal_id);
           }

}
```

while doing this i get the following error at the end.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

NOTE - It does print out the correct set of data..just getting this error at the end. any reason why??

Comment: my simple advice is segregate the properties in some other class and add in your List

Comment: sorry it was remove.. wierd. I created my own class of Basic pay and i am trying to get it into a List<BasicPay>

Comment: then see my answer. it will help you. Because you cann't straight a way add the values, because you mentioned "BasicPay" class in the List. so you can only add the "BasicPay" type in List. That's the purpose i added a new "BasicPay" class and assigned the values, then added into the IList

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert an anonymous object into a List 
Simply do something like so:

```
 var query = from c in context.Employee_Financial
                        join d in context.Employee_Employ on
                        c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id equals d.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id
                        where c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == empPersionalinfoID
                        select 
         new BasicPay 
         {
                  position_id = blah.ID,
                  housing = blah.Housing

        };
//I'm making stuff up as the property because I don't understand the stuff you are filling.
//Fill as appropriate
```

Then after:

```
var y = query.SingleOrDefault();
var basics = new List<BasicPay>();
basics.Add(y);
```

You can't do `y.ID` or `y.SomeProperty` because `y` is an `object`.. an `object` doesn't have those properties. So some of the suggested answers won't work :(

Comment: might sound like a stupid question but i now have to list.. how do i get to print it out to see if its correct. thanks in advance.

Comment: In BasicPay you can overwrite toString, so you can just have
foreach(var b in basics){
   Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}

Comment: please check my edited code above. and let me know what you think. you've been of great help, please help me with this last query. thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
basic.Add(new BasicPay { employee_personal_id = y.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id, grade_id = y.Grade_Id});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of `BasicPay` so you should put instances of this type into the list:

```
basic.Add(new BasicPay {employee_personal_id = y.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id, grade_id = y.Grade_Id});
```

Comment: The class name is BasicPay

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below solution will help you

```
BasicPay objPay = new BasicPay();
   objPay.employee_personal_id  = y.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id;
   objPay.grade_id              = y.Grade_Id;

   basic.Add ( objPay );
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Either you are missing constructor or you have to initialize it from default one:

```
public BasicPay(int empId, int gradeId)
{
    --> here initialization
}
```

or as you set all properties public you can use default constructor:

```
basic.Add(new BasicPay
{
   employee_personal_id=y.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id,
   grade_id = y.Grade_Id
});
```